# Problem passing C++ comparator functor as a parameter

Tags: c++, functor

Suppose I have a template class called LinkedList that also contains a method called Sort
I want to be able to have a default comparator which is assuming the type T can be compared with the < operator.

However, I want to be able to override that for other types.

This is part of a custom library that I'm extending.  No STL.

e.g.

```
template <class T, class Comparator<T> >
class LinkedList
{
  ...
  Node* MergeSort(Node* list)
  {
      ...
      if (Comparator<T>(nodeA,nodeB))
      ...
  }
  ...
};


typedef Pair<int, int> ListEntry;

struct sorter
{
    inline sorter(){}
    inline bool operator()(ListEntry const& a, ListEntry const& b)
    {
        return a.second < b.second;
    }
};

Pair<int, int> entry;
LinkedList<ListEntry, sorter()> list;

list.PushFront( ListEntry(5,9) );
list.PushFront( ListEntry(77,5) );
list.PushFront( ListEntry(4,1) );
list.PushFront( ListEntry(8,44) );
list.PushFront( ListEntry(1,64) );
list.PushFront( ListEntry(3,5) );
n = list.MergeSort(node* n);
```

This is roughly what my class looks like.  Actually MergeSort is a private data member but I've temporarily made it public just while I fool around and try to make it work.  MergeSort will eventually be called by Sort.

I haven't been able to compile this.  Just wondering how you would normally pass Functor objects around like this.

Comment: How about you tell us what compiler errors you get, if you want us to solve them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot say `template <class T, class Comparator<T>>`, i.e. have one template parameter be itself a parameter of another parameter. Do it like the standard library does it and use default parameters:

```
template <class T, class Comparator = std::less<T>>
class MyClass
{
  ...
}
```

Also, `Comparator` is going to be an object that you need to instantiate at some point. Again, default arguments are the key:

```
void MyClass::doSomething(Foo x, Comparator comp = Comparator())
{
  /* ... */
  if (comp(a, b)) { /* ... */ }
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That seems to make sense.  However I'm getting some compiler errors.  See updates above.

Comment: Sorted!  never mind.  I had a typo.  thanks alot for your help.

Comment: I think you need a space between the 2 `>`s at the end of your template declaration: `template <class T, class Comparator = std::less<T> >` for it to compile with g++ at least.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a reason why the functor type should be part of the type of the list: if it's a straight linked list sorting is not part of the invariants and of what the list does *unless* when calling the `MergeSort` member specifically. I'd suggest making it a template parameter of that member:

```
template<typename T>
struct LinkedList {
    template<typename Functor>
    Node*
    MergeSort(Node* node, Functor f) {
        // ...
        if(f(NodeA, NodeB)) {
            // ...
        }
        // ...
     }
};
```

Comment: Hm, yes, of course -- I was only looking at the trees, not the forest. That said, how much more are we going to copy from `std::list` into this post? :-)